# Web services while deploying in tomcat server

Tags: java, web-services

I have developed java weblogic webservices using the following url( http://gerardnico.com/wiki/weblogic/web_service). It is working fine when I deploy it in weblogic server, but it is giving an error when I deploy it in tomcat.
Could someone guide me in the right direction.

The error I can see in tomcat logs is :

> Jun 8, 2015 4:05:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: Marking servlet DataServiceServlethttp as unavailable Jun 8,
>   2015 4:05:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
>   SEVERE: Servlet /TEST_TOMCAT threw load() exception
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.TestData cannot be cast to
>   javax.servlet.Servlet     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1148)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5518)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1879)
>     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Jun 8, 2015 4:05:35 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: Marking servlet
>   DataServiceServlethttp as unavailable

Comment: Can you post the code of com.test.TestData?

Comment: com.test.TestData cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet. Does your class com.test.TestData extend HttpServlet?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick reply...........package com.test;
import javax.jws.WebService;
@WebService(name="DataPortType", serviceName="DataService")

public class TestData {
  // By default, all public methods are exposed as Web Services operation
  public String sayHelloWorld(String message) {
  try {
    System.out.println("sayHelloWorld:" + message);
  } catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
 
    return "Here is the message: '" + message + "'";
  }
}

Comment: my code will not extend servlet...as it is a basic webservice class, i have followed the ( http://gerardnico.com/wiki/weblogic/web_service ) to create webservices